# Ember : children views using checkboxes

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

in ember, I have a list of cars, and for each cars the same set of colors.

I'd like to present the user with a list of cars and the ability to tick the color he wants for each.

I have built the following example http://jsfiddle.net/eH9xH/7/ but can't figure out how to avoid the color being selected for each and every car. Can you help ?

Thanks, and sorry for the newbie question.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{#each App.availableCopies.content }}
        <h1>{{ this.value }}</h1>
        {{each App.availableTags.content itemViewClass="App.OneTagView"}}
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="one-tag">
    <label>
       {{ view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isChecked" }}
       {{ name }}
    </label>
</script>
```

Comment: Can I ask why you've chosen to use checkboxes rather than radio buttons or a select box?

Comment: Bradley : because i was only trying to understand how ember worked, not finding the best UI. Once I understand a bit better how it works, you're right, select probably makes more sense.

Comment: I was criticizing, but for usecase a select/radio would be easier to implement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/apWsW/3/

basically, `checkedBinding="isChecked"` binds to the enclosing context, which is not what we want here. Since the context is shared among rest of the OneTagView instances, the checkBinding is updating all of them

If you change it to `checkedBinding=view.isChecked`, it binds to the **instance** of the OneTagView.

Hope this helps

Comment: Why not "isChecked" bind to one of the property of the car object?

Comment: I don't like mixing UI concerns with the Model layer. 'isChecked' is a view property, and would be mostly used in some logic implemented in Controller/Router layer.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `checkedBinding` to `view.isChecked` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eH9xH/9/) and as Bradley suggested, you can use Radio button or a dropdown list for the colors if it is going to be the same for every car...